# sprintf with visual studio, variadic parameters are not detected properly with certain character combination

Tags: c++

I'm working with the MAME source and have this line of code (using VS2015):

```
sprintf(mac, "\x02\x60\x8c%c%c%c", (num >> 16) & 0xff, (num >> 8) & 0xff, num & 0xff);
```

When I compile, I get this warning:

```
2>..\..\..\..\..\src\devices\bus\isa\3c503.cpp(33): warning C4474: 'sprintf' : too many arguments passed for format string
2>         ..\..\..\..\..\src\devices\bus\isa\3c503.cpp(33): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
2>         ..\..\..\..\..\src\devices\bus\isa\3c503.cpp(33): note: placeholders and their parameters expect 2 variadic arguments, but 3 were provided
```

So it's only detecting 2 of the %c. It seems the last c in the 3rd hex number is the culprit, but I don't understand why the two are conflicting.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. Maybe `sprintf(mac, "\x02\x60\x8c" "%c%c%c", ...);` can help it out?

Comment: Good suggestion, but still got same warning unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, seems to have to do with \x8c being a unicode character, i was getting a warning about that but didn't realize it was on the same line.